# Display SubTotal and Grand Total in ASP.Net DataGrid in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagrid

There was a topic about this question but in ASP.NET GridView not DataGrid. I want to convert it to **DataGrid** in order to look like this:
[image]

```
 int currentId = 0;
decimal subTotal = 0;
decimal total = 0;
int subTotalRowIndex = 0;
protected void OnRowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    subTotal = 0;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataTable dt = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).DataView.Table;
        int orderId = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["OrderID"]);
        total += Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["Price"]);
        if (orderId != currentId)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowIndex > 0)
            {
                for (int i = subTotalRowIndex; i < e.Row.RowIndex; i++)
                {
                    subTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
                }
                this.AddTotalRow("Sub Total", subTotal.ToString("N2"));
                subTotalRowIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
            }
            currentId = orderId;
        }
    }
}

private void AddTotalRow(string labelText, string value)
{
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
    row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#F9F9F9");
    row.Cells.AddRange(new TableCell[3] { new TableCell (), //Empty Cell
                                        new TableCell { Text = labelText, HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right},
                                        new TableCell { Text = value, HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right } });

    GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.Add(row);
}

protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = subTotalRowIndex; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        subTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text);
    }
    this.AddTotalRow("Sub Total", subTotal.ToString("N2"));
    this.AddTotalRow("Total", total.ToString("N2"));
}
```

So, any guys please convert it to DataGrid because I never use GridView in my project. Thanks!